# Set sessionStorage expiration

Tags: javascript

I have this code which sets a sessionStorage. It works fine but I would like to set an expiration **date of 24 hours**. Can I do this? I know this can be done with cookies but not sure with sessionStorage objets.

```
<script>
  
  var pageViewed = parseInt("1");
  
  if(sessionStorage.pageViewed)
  {
    var intSessionStoragePageViewed = parseInt(sessionStorage.pageViewed);
    pageViewed =  intSessionStoragePageViewed + 1;
    sessionStorage.setItem("pageViewed", pageViewed);
  }
  else if(!sessionStorage.pageViewed)
  {
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("pageViewed", pageViewed);
  }
  
  </script>
```

Comment: `sessionStorage`'s value is accessible only for the browser tab/window from which it was set. Other browser tabs, even for the same URL, would have their independent sessionStorage sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage and sessionStorage do not have built-in expiration dates like cookies do.  sessionStorage is erased at the end of the browser session; localStorage is erased only when you or the end user explicitly erases it.

If you want locally stored data to expire after a specific duration, use cookies.